# ServiceStack.OrmLite inheritance mapping

Tags: c#, .net, ormlite-servicestack

Does ServiceStack.OrmLite support inheritance mapping?

Like DevExpress XPO: [Inheritance Mapping](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/2125/DevExpress-ORM-Tool/Concepts/Inheritance-Mapping) or nHibernate [Inheritance](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/inheritance.html).

For example (c#):

```
public abstract class EventBase
{
   public string Name { get;set; }
}
public class NormalEvent: EventBase
{
   public string A { get;set; }
}
public class SuperDuppaEvent:EventBase
{
   public string B { get;set; }
}
```

In database exist one table 'EventBase' with all Columns/Properties from 'NormalEvent', 'SuperDuppaEvent' and from 'EventBase' too.

In the documentation exist the 'AliasAttribute' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No OrmLite does not support inheritance mapping. It's a core expectation in OrmLite that each POCO maps 1:1 with the RDBMS table it represents. So by default each of your classes will map to an RDBMS table with the same name:

- `NormalEvent` > NormalEvent table
- `SuperDuppaEvent` > SuperDuppaEvent table

If you want different behavior you'd need to map the POCO classes 1:1 with how you want it laid out in the database, e.g:

```
class NormalEvent
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int EventBaseId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So if all 15 of your DB tables have Id, RowVersion, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, you have to re-define those 4 fields 15 times in your POCOs?  Would be nice if there was a way to define a base class and have all 15 inherit from it and automatically get the common fields.  Is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: @Bitfiddler you can use inheritance as normal but the fields are included in each POCOs table, I.e. they’re not mapped to a different table. POCOs always map 1:1 to their underlying table, if you want common fields in a different table you’d need to define the separate table and relationship accordingly, there’s no magical mapping to different tables.

Comment: Oh, excellent.  Then what I was after should be possible by default?  A 'TransactionalBase' with the 4 fields common to all POCOs should be mapped down to each individual table seperately?  Ok, time to try this :-)